# circle visible when mouse hover to 5 meter circle area

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a 5 meter circle on google map, I would like by default it's invisible, when mouse hover to that 5 meters area, then make the cycle visible.

I tried `myCircle.setVisible(false);`, but after that, mouse event could not be triggered, so I am not sure how to handle it.

```
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    zoom: 8,
  });
  const radius = 5; // meters
  const myCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
  strokeColor: "#FF0000",
  strokeOpacity: 1,
  strokeWeight: 1,
  fillColor: "#FF0000",
  fillOpacity: 0,
  map: map,
  center: map.getCenter(),
  radius: radius,
});
    var visible = false
    myCircle.setVisible(visible);
    myCircle.addListener('mouseover', function() {
    console.log("mouseover")
            visible = !visible
            myCircle.setVisible(visible);

    });
    myCircle.addListener('mouseout', function() {
    console.log("mouseout")
            visible = !visible
            myCircle.setVisible(visible);           
    });     

  map.fitBounds(myCircle.getBounds())
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a circle not visible, but still respond to mouse events, set the `strokeWeight` and the `fillOpacity` to 0. As you indicated in your comment, if you set the circle to `visible:false`, the mouse events don't work.

```
 const myCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
 strokeColor: "#FF0000",
 strokeOpacity: 0.8,
 strokeWeight: 0,       // set to 0
 fillColor: "#FF0000",
 fillOpacity: 0.0,      // set to 0
 map: map,
 center: map.getCenter(),
 radius: radius,
});
```

Then on the `mouseover` event, set the `strokeWeight` and `fillOpacity` to your desired values, set them back to zero on `mouseout`:

```
  myCircle.addListener("mouseover", function(evt) {
     this.setOptions({
     strokeWeight:2,
     fillOpacity: 0.35
     });
  });
    myCircle.addListener("mouseout",   function(evt) {
     this.setOptions({
     strokeWeight:0,
     fillOpacity: 0.0
     });
  })
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/s1hec8r9/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    zoom: 8,
  });
  const radius = 5; // meters
  const myCircle = new google.maps.Circle({
  strokeColor: "#FF0000",
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 0,
  fillColor: "#FF0000",
  fillOpacity: 0.0,
  map: map,
  center: map.getCenter(),
  radius: radius,
});
  myCircle.addListener("mouseover", function(evt) {
     this.setOptions({
     strokeWeight:2,
     fillOpacity: 0.35
     });
  });
    myCircle.addListener("mouseout",   function(evt) {
     this.setOptions({
     strokeWeight:0,
     fillOpacity: 0.0
     });
  })

  map.fitBounds(myCircle.getBounds())
}

window.initMap = initMap;
```

```css
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */
/* 
 * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
 * that contains the map. 
 */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* 
 * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
 */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
 @license
 Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
-->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- 
     The `defer` attribute causes the callback to execute after the full HTML
     document has been parsed. For non-blocking uses, avoiding race conditions,
     and consistent behavior across browsers, consider loading using Promises
     with https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/js-api-loader.
    -->
 <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```